# IPhone UIWebView Application wit AJAX

Tags: ios, html, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I'm doing now an iPhone App that encapsulate a web Site inside a `UIWebView`, the first request is made by the iphone app and it activate the "`webViewDidFinishLoad`" delegate, but when i press on one of the buttons in the web application inside the `UIWebView` this delegate is not working, do i need to do anything more in the `ViewController` or in the Html?
I Think i understand the specific problem: the next calls from the `UIWebView` are AJAX calls and it does not monitored by the `webViewDidFinishLoad`, i need some help, anyone know how to handle AJAC calls from UIWebView?
Thanks

Shimon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is to add UIGestureRecognizer to the UIWebView, and in the handler read the UIWebView string, then you can see the AJAX Updates done after the UIWebView was loaded for the first time' solved my problem